# How can an XMPP client retrieve online users from the server?

Tags: javascript, xmpp

I am creating a chat application using XMPP with javascript. If I log in with `malini@example.com`, I get the online users list, which includes `malini@example.com`, `someone@example.com`. It keeps on repeating the same IDs. Why it is working like this?

It generates my ID like `malini@example.com/somenumber`, and also other IDs like `someone@example.com/somenumber`. I think that this is maintaining some session and keeps on generating the same IDs.

Please help me to solve this issue. I am new to XMPP server.

Answer (score 0):

You do not "retrieve" online user from server in XMPP. Basically, you subscribe to presence, as defined in [XMPP RFC 6121](http://xmpp.org/rfcs/rfc6121.html#sub). If your contact has allowed you to get the presence, you will receive it for online users on login and as they change during your XMPP session.